# Can't connect to SQL Server Analysis Services from Excel

Tags: excel, ssas

My problem is, before, I could connect to my SSAS DB from Excel with no problems. Now, all I'm getting is: Data could not be retrieved from the database.

I can connect to the DB from SSMS and Power BI. It's only in Excel that I'm having this problem.

TIA